Пропадает компонент React при изменении состояния
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, уже сутки не могу понять что к чему. Есть карточки товаров, при клике на кнопку в карточке, товар пушится в массив, из этого массива другой компонент(корзина) отрисовывает собственно тот товар, на который был совершен клик(добавить в корзину). То есть банальное добавление товаров в корзину, но, чтобы в корзину не добавлялось 2 одинаковых товара, я написал проверку и если такой товар уже присутствует в массиве, то в корзине должно меняться только цифра в строке "Количество"
let basketItem = [];
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
const addItem = (item) => {
  basketItem.includes(item) ? setQuantity(quantity + 1) : basketItem.push(item);
}

Пропсами всё передается в шапку, где находится компонент корзины
return (
<div className='app'>
  <Header {...{
    expand: 'md',
    fixed: 'top',
    color: 'light'
  }}
  cities={cities}
  basketItem={basketItem}
  quantity={quantity}
  />

Вот кнопка, по которой всё происходит
<Button onClick={() => props.addItem(item)}>

А вот код компонента Корзины
function Basket(props) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  let arrItems = props.basketItem;
  console.log(props.quantity)

  function renderItems(arr) {
    const items =  arr.map((item, i) => {
      console.log(props.basketItem)
      return (
        <div
          key={i}>
          <Row>
            <Col sm="12">
              <Card body>
                <CardTitle tag="h5">
                  {item.name} | Количество: {props.quantity}
                </CardTitle>
                <Button>
                  Go somewhere
                </Button>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      )
    });

    return (
      <>
        {items}
      </>
    )
  }

  const itemsDone = renderItems(arrItems)
  return (
    <>
      <img src={basket} className="basket" onClick={toggle} />
      <Offcanvas toggle={toggle}
                 isOpen={isOpen}
                 direction="end"
                 scrollable>
        <OffcanvasHeader toggle={toggle}>
          Корзина
        </OffcanvasHeader>
        <OffcanvasBody>
          {itemsDone}
        </OffcanvasBody>
      </Offcanvas>
    </>
  );
}

export default Basket;

Проблема в том, что если товар добавлен в Корзину, то повторный клик по "Добавить в корзину" удаляет из корзины все товары, но если кликнуть еще раз, то товары снова появляются с уже обновленным и актуальным стейтом(количество: 2) Вообще не понимаю почему  так происходит, почему для нормального отображения на кнопку нужно кликать 2 раза. Буду очень признателен за подсказки.
Товар - это объект. Пример товара:
{
  name: "shovel1",
  top: 1,
  img: "https://remitek.ru/files/2020/09_22/14_09/u_files_store_1_1373036.jpg",
  type: "Bayonet",

},

Карточка товара:
<Card
                  style={{
                    width: '18rem'
                  }}
                >
                  <img
                    alt="Sample"
                    src={item.img}
                  />
                  <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle tag="h5">
                      {item.name}
                    </CardTitle>
                    <CardText>
                      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card‘s content.
                    </CardText>
                    <Button onClick={() => props.addItem(item)}>
                      Button
                    </Button>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>


Проблема понятна. Где у вас находится вот это let basketItem = [];? Это должно быть состоянием компонента, это раз

Находится в App.jsx, там же где функция addItem, которая вызывается в карточке товара, при нажатии на Button. Извините, не совсем понимаю, массив объектов сделать состоянием компонента? Что это даст?
У меня ситуация такая, что по кнопке вызывается функция у общего родителя (так как карточка и корзина - разные компоненты), чтобы результат её выполнения уже собственно через пропсы прокинуть ребенку(корзине)

Все переменные состояния должны быть созданы с useState. Иначе каждый рендер компонента будет создавать новые переменные. У вас правда проблема немного в другом. Сейчас оформлю ответ

React перерисовывает компонент, только в том случае, если изменились переменные состояния или пропс компонента.
Так же, javaScript передает массивы и объекты по ссылкам и изменение содержимого не приводит к изменению ссылки, поэтому и React не видит изменения при push.
Необходимо передавать новый массив и положить его в состояние компонента, что бы React его отслеживал
const [basketItem, setBasketItem] = useState([]);
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
const addItem = (item) => {
  if (basketItem.includes(item)) {
    setQuantity(quantity + 1)
  } else {
    setBasketItem(prev => {
      prev.push(item);
      return [ ...prev ];
    })
  }
}

А на quantity реагировал, потому как первый клик - пуш элемента и ничего не происходит, второй клик, пуша нет, но есть изменение состояния компонента.
И я бы изменил формат хранения данных в корзине на массив объектов, вот так:
const [basketItem, setBasketItem] = useState([]);
const addItem = (item) => {
  const elem = basketItem.find(i => i.name === item);
  if (elem) {
    elem.quantity += 1;
  } else {
    basketItem.push({
      name: item,
      quantity: 1
    });
  }
  setBasketItem([ ...basketItem ]);
}

Теперь у вас каждый товар будет содержать информацию о названии и количестве в корзине
UPD после обновления вопроса:
т.к. товар это изначально объект, то можно при добавлении товара в корзину, добавлять поле quantity.
const [basketItem, setBasketItem] = useState([]);
const addItem = (item) => {
  const elem = basketItem.find(i => i.name === item);
  if (elem) {
    elem.quantity += 1;
  } else {
    basketItem.push({ ...item, quantity: 1 });
  }
  setBasketItem([ ...basketItem ]);
}

В то же время, includes для объектов не подходит(конечно можно использовать для поиска одинаковых объектов, но в данном случае этого делать не стот)

Хм, да, я понял о чем речь, спасибо) Но решения ваши почему-то не подходят, в случае с первым - всё равно добавляется 2 и более одинаковых товара в корзину(как будто игнорируется if (basketItem.includes(item))) А второе выдает ошибку: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, top, img, type, quantity}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
Возможно я как-то не правильно вставил в код, попробую ещё покопаться) Спасибо вам за объяснение с перерисовкой компонентов, буду знать.

@Monteg includes сработает, если item это число или строка. Если это объект, то нужен другой подход. Второй пример потребует изменения рендера элементов корзины

@Monteg Добавьте в вопрос пример item - вашего товара. Что это? Может это изначально объект?

Да, вы правы, товар - это объект, добавил примеры в вопрос

@Monteg Дополнил ответ

Огромная вам благодарность, всё работает) И конструкция очень хороша для модернизации, на + и - кол-во товаров в корзине, немного доработал и всё отлично, теперь всё через одну функцию работает ) Только, подскажите, пожалуйста, я не совсем понимаю, что делает строчка setBasketItem([ ...basketItem ]); ?
Мы пушим объект в массив basketItem.push({ ...item, quantity: 1 });, но почему напрямую? Без setBasketItem?  Я вроде знаю значение всех операций, но не до конца понимаю как работает. Буду очень благодарен если объясните

@Monteg в elem попадает элемент массива, т.к. это объект, он передается по ссылке, поэтому мутирует(когда в if попадает). Когда пушится элемент, ссылка на массив не меняется и реакт не заметит изменений. Хотя по хорошему, пушить надо так, как указано во 1-м примере - в предыдущее состояние). И если обратите внимание, то сеттер стоит после if и как раз сохраняет "новое значение". а [ ...basketItem ] как раз создает "новый" массив(поверхностное копирование) - это называется спред оператор. Уделите час своего времени, перечитайте про методы массивов, особенно которые используете. Очень полезно.

Большое спасибо за объяснение, обязательно почитаю, так как хочется хорошо понимать, как всё работает )

@Monteg Удачи! Будут вопросы, заходите
